# Java "Cannot be resolved" to object array reference.

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have recently been trying to tackle a problem involving object arrays, and I can't seem to wrap my head around the problems with the "scope of the object".

I have the following code, and on these lines:

```
ccaA[n].outputInfo("CCA");
```

and

```
clientA[n].outputInfo("Client");
```

I get the following error:

```
clientA cannot be resolved to a variable
```

which confused me since it was made not 10 lines above.

Could a proficent Java programmer explain this to me?

```
public class MakePersonV2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n; // Index number 
        int ccaNum, clientNum; // Number of Clients & CCA's to be created

        // introduction
        System.out.println("This main program creates a client and CCA object, "
                + "ensures their data\nfields are assigned values, and finally "
                + "outputs those values.");

        ccaNum = PersonInfoV2.inputQuestion("CCA");
        clientNum = PersonInfoV2.inputQuestion("Client");


        for (n = 0; n <= ccaNum; n++)
        {
            // create a CCA and input CCA's information
            System.out.println("\n\nCreating a CCA and entering information...");
            PersonInfoV2[] ccaA = new PersonInfoV2[n]; // create CCA Object Array
            ccaA[n].inputName();                        // assign a name
            ccaA[n].inputAge();                     // assign an age
            ccaA[n].inputGender();                      // assign a gender
        }

        // create a client and input client's information

        for (n = 0; n <= clientNum; n++)
        {
            System.out.println("\n\nCreating a client and entering information...");
            PersonInfoV2[] clientA = new PersonInfoV2[n];// create Client Object Array
            clientA[n].inputCCAName();                       // assign a name
            clientA[n].inputAge();                      // assign an age
            clientA[n].inputGender();                       // assign a gender

        }



        // output client and CCA information
        for (n = 0; n <= clientNum; n++)
        {
            ccaA[n].outputInfo("CCA");                  // output CCA information
        }

        for (n = 0; n <= clientNum; n++)
        {
            clientA[n].outputInfo("Client");            // output Client information
        }

    } // main

} // end MakePerson
```

Comment: `ccaA` and `clientA` will have only `n` elements, so you must not access `ccaA[n]` and `clientA[n]` unless you change the creation of array.

Comment: Scope-- it's all about scope. Your variable is not visible where you want to use it, so you must declare it in a scope that allows it to be visible where needed.

Comment: It's only visible within the for loop. Declare it **before** the for loop so that it is visible inside and outside the loop. But again, look up variable scope, since this is a concept that you need to understand *cold*.

Comment: So, why does this not work? http://pastebin.com/vRDTTYVE

Its declared outside the array - if this doesn't work, how does this whole thing work? >.<. *Sigh - I should stick to C*